# How to return the whole list from a python function

Tags: python, boto3

I have a small script as follows:

```
import boto3
ACCESS_KEY= "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
SECRET_KEY= "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
for region in regions:
  client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
  addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
  for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
     print eip_dict['PublicIp']
```

This code works fine and prints the list of all EIP's from ALL region, now i am trying to use the above code in my another script using functions as :

```
def gather_public_ip():
   ACCESS_KEY = config.get('aws','access_key')
   SECRET_KEY = config.get('aws','secret_key')
   regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
   all_EIP = []
   for region in regions:
      client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
      addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
      for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
          print eip_dict['PublicIp']
          all_EIP.append(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
          return all_EIP
```

**But this breaks after 1st iteration only (it just prints one IP) and doesn't return the whole list to caller**, i am calling the above function from `__main__` as follows :

```
       net_range =  gather_public_ip()
       r = s.run(net_range)
       s.save()   # save
```

Basically i want to pass the list of returned ip's to `run()`. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return your `all_EIP` in the first iteration of the nested for loop. Indent the return so it gets executed after the outer for and you should have all of what is supposed to get appended.

```
def gather_public_ip():
   ACCESS_KEY = config.get('aws','access_key')
   SECRET_KEY = config.get('aws','secret_key')
   regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
   all_EIP = []
   for region in regions:
      client = boto3.client('ec2',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,region_name=region,)
      addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
      for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
          print eip_dict['PublicIp']
          all_EIP.append(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
   return all_EIP
```

Comment: ahh , silly me, and just one more question to follow it up, as you can see i am picking up the credentials from a configuration file, will it also work for `regions` ,

Comment: The `ConfigParser` module has no built-in way to handle input/output of lists. You will have to roll your own, but that's simple enough. For example using a seperator character between regions and then splitting on that after `get`.

Comment: can you tell me how do i get the IP's which are actually having a running instance only??

Comment: Nope. Probably better to make a new question.